# File owner and group changes and not able inherit folder permission

Tags: permissions

I have a folder called abc in which owner is "node" and group is "angulargroup" and folder has 777 permission , but if someone creates a file inside abc folder all the permissions gets changed.

I need to set permission so that if any user create files inside this folder , the owner , group and permission should not change for that files.

I am attaching a pic for the reference:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

This is not how permissions work. When someone creates a file/folder in a location where he/she has the permissions, the user and group are these of the user.

The user of a created file will always be the user who created the file/folder. Else, there would be false information. The only way to create a file as a specific user is to assume the role of that user, either by logging in as that user or with `sudo -u` (or `sudo -u ... -g ...` to act as another user and specific group).

The group, however, can be set to be the group of the current folder. For this to happen, the setgid flag must be set on that folder: `chmod g+s <dir>`. From then on, the group of any item created in `<dir>` will be the group of that `<dir>` instead of the group of the current user. It speaks for itself that users must be member of that group for this to work.